# Send variable with EOF and use host variable

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting, variable, here-document

I want to send variable from source to host, and exec host script.
Here is my code :

```
var1=1
ssh -p 42 root@xxx /bin/bash << EOF
  var2=2
  echo $var1
  echo $var2
EOF
```

Return : `1`

```
var1=1
ssh -p 42 root@xxx /bin/bash << \EOF
  var2=2
  echo $var1
  echo $var2
EOF
```

Return : `2`

How to return :

```
1
2
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want your local shell to expand `$var1` but the remote shell to expand `$var2`:

```
var1=1
ssh -p 42 root@xxx /bin/bash << EOF    # un-quoted/escaped
  var2=2
  echo $var1
  echo \$var2
EOF
```